# is there any option to move last alphabet of textview text somewhat upside?

Tags: android

we can move TextView string upside by using property

```
 android:paddingBottom="4dp"
```

i want to move last alphabet of a TextView string(not all the string) to somewhat upside.

Answer (score 3):

`tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>2</sup>"));`

Comment: its going much above, how can i adjust?

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna try `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup><small>2</small></sup>"));`

Comment: no, its only making that alphabet small, placement still not correct

Answer (score 3):

```
    String string="ASIA";
    String s=string.substring(string.length()-1,string.length());
  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(string+"<sup>"+s+"</sup>"));
```

This may not the exact solution, But i think this can help you, Substring the last character and use this code.

Comment: is there any option to give how much it has to move upside

Comment: May be not, I am not sure